# How to change client_max_body_size of nginx in docker

Tags: docker, nginx

I deployed my application backend with docker. I used the Alpine Linux image and installed php-fpm and nginx on it. Now I want to change the maximum upload size. The `nginx.conf` file on the container is not changeable and contains an http section whose last phrase is `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf`. I have a 'nginx.conf' file locally, add `client_max_body_sizecopy 5m` to it and then copy it to `etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` file on container (Using COPY command - Dockerfile). But the upload size does not change. Where should these changes be applied?

Comment: you can change `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` in runtime, either you mount a file to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` or create a docker config and map it to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Comment: You can check this github issue: https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy/issues/690